# Spring boot website works locally but not accessible remotely

Tags: java, spring-boot, deployment

I was learning to program a website using spring boot and was trying to deploy a working version of my project to my cloud server. I used `mvn clean install` to build it in to a `.jar` file locally, then I uploaded it to my cloud server via `sftp` and ran it with `java -jar mywebapp.jar`.

Next I entered `[my-server-ip]:8080` in my browser and got an empty response error. So I ssh on to my server and ran `w3m http://localhost:8080`, and w3m loaded the page successfully, which means the website is running correctly.

I checked `netstat -np` and I got this:

```
tcp6       0      0 :::8080                 :::*                    LISTEN      7297/java        off (0.00/0/0)
```

The cloud server is running Ubuntu 16.04

Any idea what's happening here?

Comment: sounds like a network problem. Can you reach your server on the 8080?

Comment: No, I can't. I tried 'ping [my-server-ip] -P 8080' and got 100% packet loss. I thought it was because icmp was disabled, but then I tried 'ssh [my-server-ip] -p 8080' and still cannot reach the server.

Comment: I don't want to know how did you ping(udp) with a port number but if you are sure that you cannot reach the sever on the 8080 you need a reverse proxy that accept calls on the 80 and route you to the internal 8080. IF you search spring boot nginx reverse proxy you'll find it in minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it's an issue with the firewall setting that's blocking all inbound traffic except ssh through port 22. I added a rule to allow incoming http traffic on port 8080 and now it's working fine.